# What is the difference between ‘to meet’ and ‘to get acquainted’?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I’ve been learning English for a long time but, unfortunately, I’ve never lived in an English speaking country. And this is a huge problem. Every time I want to say something I realise that there are some options and I am not sure which one l should use in a specific situation. For example, I meet someone on the beach and want to know the person’s name and where he/she comes from, is it possible to use the phrase ‘let’s get acquainted’? If not, what is the appropriate way to do that?

Comment: The sentence is grammatical, but not particularly natural. You would probably introduce yourself first - "I'm Irina from XXX." and expect the other person to then tell you their name etc.

Comment: If you say to an English stranger that you just met 'lets get acquainted' they'd probably smile uncertainly, say 'Er, yes, certainly!' and get away as fast as they can.

Answer (score 2):

"Let's get acquainted" is mostly used in situations where it's clearly beneficial to both people. Like if a business person and a politician meet and realize they might be of benefit to each other, one might say, "Let's get acquainted", meaning, "Let's get to know each other better so that we can decide if we'd like to form some kind of working relationship."

In a social setting, you wouldn't use any expression like "Let's get acquainted." Instead, you would just start doing it: talking about yourself, asking them questions about themselves, or suggesting something you can do together, like walk on the beach. These things *show* an interest in getting acquainted, rather than saying it.

Answer (score 1):

A first person request to get acquainted with someone is not a common usage, although it makes perfect sense and everyone would understand what you were requesting.

In the U.S. if you wanted to *get acquainted* with someone, you would be more likely to suggest an activity, such as *let's go get lunch*, that would allow you to get acquainted.  A person you just met would interpret that as an opportunity for you to get acquainted.  A straightforward request to *get acquainted* might seem a bit odd.